# Firebase storage - PutData and download not being called when expected

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-storage

I'm making an app that involves an image view, the first time the user logs in they upload a photo to be their photo, like so:

```
let storage = FIRStorage.storage()

        let storageRef = storage.referenceForURL("gs:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx")
        let picRef = storageRef.child("images/" + "myname" + ".jpg")
        let data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(pickedImage)
        forceUpload(profPicRef, data: data!)

    let uploadTask = picRef.putData(data, metadata: nil) { metadata, error in
        if (error != nil) {
            print(error)
        } else {
            print("uploaded")
            // Metadata contains file metadata such as size, content-type, and download URL.
            let downloadURL = metadata!.downloadURL
        }
    }
}
```

and then the next time they come back to this view controller, in ViewDidAppear I have this code that should download the picture and put it into the image View:

```
 picRef.dataWithMaxSize(1 * 4096 * 4096) { (data, error) -> Void in
        print("in download")
        if (error != nil) {
            print(error)
        } else {
            retPic = UIImage(data: data!)!
```

and then I set retPic to be the image view's image. The problem is, these methods are seemingly called at random. WHen I first go into this view controller, no picture appears in the image view and "in download" isn't printed. Also when I upload a picture, it isn't always uploaded and "uploaded" doesn't always print. After switching back and forth into this view controller again it eventually seems to load at random. I am wondering why these putData and dataWithMaxSize functions are called at seemingly random times, and how to force them to occur when I want them too. I had this issue with snapshots too, and moving them into ViewWillAppear seemed to work, but not here.

Thanks!

Comment: Would you mind posting the full source (where these are being called in the activity lifecycle)? I have a feeling that you're hitting issues with the lifecycle combined with asynchronous programming, rather than randomness in Firebase Storage.

Comment: the upload is stored in a function when a user presses a button, calls an ImagePicker and then shold return the function. The download is called in viewDidAppear